# How to get Facebook Logged in user UID in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to get facebook logged in user UID in firebase? For users logged in using email authentication, it creates the UID automatically in the Firebase Database. This is the code I'm using `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`

Comment: Once a user is signed in with Firebase Authentication they have a UID. You retrieve this UID with `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`, no matter what provider they are signed in with. If you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).